# Rebus- Wind OW!

Tags: rebus

My last rebus puzzle got solved pretty quickly, so I came up with a slightly harder one!

[image]

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: No clue. Upvoted to cancel one out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, oh! I think I've got this!

> Window pane

Reasoning:

> Putting all the letters together gets you "window"
>  The "OW!" is meant to indicate "pain" which is a homonym for "pane" or the section of glass.

Comment: Yes, Yes you have! Correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be

> Wind down the window

?

Comment: Sorry! that isn't it.... you're on the right track! :D